# how to find and delete records that have only numeric values

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in Mongo
let's say collection name is 'invoices'
The value of _id is generated by a script (not default mongo ID object)
the type of _id is a string.

I want to find all record in which the _id is all numeric string. I mean string like "3434349898"

Can this be done with a query?

The final goal is I want to delete all such records (that have numeric values of _id) and leave only non-numeric. So "a234" or "4898c" should be left in the collection but values with only number chars should be deleted.

If this cannot be done with one query, what's the best query to delete these records in a loop? There could be about half a million or records that match this condition our of about million and a half of total record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the type of `_id` is a string, you could use a regular expression to remove documents whose ids are strings that contain only digits like this:

```
db.coll.remove({"_id":/^[0-9]*$/})
```

Where "coll" is the name of the collection that you want to update.

The regular expression uses the first character of the `_id` field, so it will be able to use the index and should be pretty fast. If you want to examine the documents first before deleting them, you can use the same query document inside of a `find()`.